# Why cursor statements are not working in isql(sybase) while running in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sybase, isql

When I try to run the below SQL query from shell script am not getting any output.

```
 #!/usr/bin/sh
. /apps/sybase/15.0.2/SYBASE.sh
SYBASE_OCS=OCS-15_0
isql=$SYBASE/$SYBASE_OCS/bin/isql
$isql -b -S"dataserver" -U"user" -P"pwd" -D"XXX" -s"," -w2000 -Jroman9  <<EOF >>output.txt
create table #tmp1 (ID_CLIENT varchar(20),ID_VALUE varchar(4))
GO
insert into #tmp1 values ('1029075','10')

GO
DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR
SELECT ID_CLIENT,ID_VALUE from #tmp1
GO
DECLARE @ID1 varchar(20),
@ID2 varchar(5)

 OPEN curs
 FETCH NEXT curs INTO @ID1,@ID2
 WHILE @@sqlstatus = 0
 BEGIN
 PRINT '* ID_CUTT_OFF: %1! ', @ID1
 EXEC BAU_U_2 'XXXX','XXXXXX','MIL',@ID1,@ID2,'FLH-123456'
 FETCH NEXT curs INTO @ID1,@ID2
  END
  CLOSE curs
  DEALLOCATE CURSOR curs
  GO
EOF
```

insert statement only executing after that cursor statement is not executing..
but same code is working if i run it on SQL browser. Can you please let me know how to execute this from shell script.

Answer (score 3):

Your last `go` has what appears to be 2 spaces in front of it.

`go` must have no white space in front of it, ie, `go` must start in column 1.

Comment: @markp.you are right. i have identified it and corrected. Its working.